# Google Sheets "repeatCell" strips formatting from existing cells

Tags: python, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to replicate a few simple keystrokes in Google sheets. I want to change the entire sheet to font `Balthazar` and size `11`. I can do this by `ctrl` + `a` and selecting the font and size in the drop down. However, I want to do it to 1000 sheets.

My problem is when I do it using the following code, it strips the existing format in the cells away. How do I avoid that?

Here is my code:

```
 align=None
 fontFamily='balthazar'
 fontSize = 11
 data={
          "requests": 
          [
            {
              "repeatCell": 
              {
                "cell": 
                {
                    "userEnteredFormat": 
                        { "horizontalAlignment": align ,   #'CENTER','LEFT','RIGHT',
                          "textFormat":  { 
                            "fontFamily": fontFamily,
                            "fontSize":  fontSize
                          }
                      }
                },
                "range": 
                {
                  "sheetId": sheetId,
                  "startRowIndex": startRowIndex,
                  "endRowIndex": endRowIndex,
                  "startColumnIndex": startColumnIndex,
                  "endColumnIndex": endColumnIndex
                },
                "fields": "userEnteredFormat"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
```

Comment: When you say "the existing formatting" what do you mean exactly... things like background color that aren't specified in the config above?

Comment: right. Things like color and the number formatting, also background color fill... haven't checked conditional formatting yet, but that's probably gone too. When you do ctrl + a, and using the drop down, you are just changing that one thing. I want to replicate that experience.

Comment: As you have discovered from the answer, this is essentially the difference between http `patch` and http `put` (i.e. `update`). Your original code sent a request saying it had the whole format data, and only supplied values for 2 of them. Thus, the rest are set to default (`put`) and not left as-is (`patch`). Since we don't have `patchCellsRequest` it is important to only identify data you want to modify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to add the new format (for example, the horizontalAlignment and textFormat) while the original formats for all cell are **NOT** modified. Namely, when "A1" has the red background color, even when the new format is added by the request body, you don't want to change the background color. If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### From :

```
"fields": "userEnteredFormat"
```

#### To :

```
"fields": "userEnteredFormat/textFormat,userEnteredFormat/horizontalAlignment"
```

By this modification, only `horizontalAlignment` and `textFormat` can be modified.

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

### Edit :

I understood that you want to change only the font family and font size. Could you please try this fields? Please modify only the fields of your request body.

```
"fields": "userEnteredFormat/textFormat/fontFamily,userEnteredFormat/textFormat/fontSize"
```

### Added :

[The document of Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request) says that `fields` is "string ([FieldMask](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/google.protobuf#google.protobuf.FieldMask) format)". So above values can be also written as follows.

```
"fields": "userEnteredFormat.textFormat.fontFamily,userEnteredFormat.textFormat.fontSize"
```

Comment: It is an improvement. number formats are intact. But still strips all font color and conditional formatting.

Comment: @jason I'm really sorry for misunderstanding your question. Unfortunately, I cannot understand what you want. I'm sorry for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about what you want? You want to clear the font colors and formats. But you don't want to change the number format is not modified. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: No need to apologize. I want to change everything on the sheet to `balthazar` font and size `11` without changing any other part of the formatting.

Comment: @jason Thank you for replying. I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: Worked! Thank you!

Comment: @jason I noticed the information for ``fields`` which should be added. So I added it. Could you please confirm it. If this will be useful for you, I'm glad.